# Manipulating form data when there are upwards of 24 forms on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wasn't sure how to word the title to this well, apologies if the question isn't what you were expecting. I have up to 24 forms on one page with a format as below:

```
<form id="prod-44" action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="meta-info">
        <span id="prodWeight1" style="font-weight:bold;">£2.99</span>
        <span id="prodWeight2" style="font-weight:bold; display:none;">£3.99</span>
        <span id="prodWeight3" style="font-weight:bold; display:none;">£4.99</span>
        <span>
            <select class="44" name="weight">
                <option value="prodWeight1">180g</option>
                <option value="prodWeight2">240g</option>
                <option value="prodWeight2">300g</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="add-to-basket">
        <input type="hidden" value="44" name="item-id">
        <input type="hidden" value="Product1" name="item-name">
        <input type="hidden" value="2.99" name="item-price">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="item-qty">
        <input class="add-product" type="submit" value="add" name="add-button">
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm now not a total noob when it comes to Jquery / JS thanks to you folks on this site, however I can't for the life of me work out how to start on this one! :) As this is one of up to 24 forms on the page at anyone time, I can't use a generic `$(this).change` method to pick up a single `<select>` value being changed. I'm trying to display the correct price based on the weight. The three `<span>` tags that are sibling elements of the selects parent are the three I'm trying to change.

I can't even post up my working Jquery as I couldn't even get it to recognise which select element has changed :( Could anyone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Comment: For one thing -- try not to name classes and ids that start with numbers. It is usually frowned upon.

Comment: I was really apprehensive about that as well, I was under the impression that the attr `class` was a CDATA type that could be fully numeric with no issues. However if it's really that frowned upon I'll definitely change it. Thanks Neal.

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to change the display of the spans prodWeight1, prodWeight2 etc. based on the value of the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function(){
 var p = $(this).parents("div");
 var c = p.find("#"+$(this).val()).html()

 // in c is now actual SPAN html text reached by id stored in select value
})
```

Comment: That works a treat! Thank you Jirka! :) I can build the rest from this now!